# how access cgroups via nodejs in macos?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, cgroups

i want access `cgroup` option for simulate docker in `macos`.
i searched SO but as they said it's implimented via `linux and unix system.`
but in **golang**  you can work with *syscall* option .
any clue or hint?

Comment: https://github.com/asbjornenge/cgroups#readme There is third party library, apparently, though it has almost 4 years of inactivity... or this: https://github.com/armPelionEdge/node-cgroups

Comment: these are for linux system's not for macos. macos doesn't support cgroups [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136335/os-level-virtualization-containers-for-os-x)

Comment: MacOS virtualization uses Hypervisor.framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacOS virtualization uses Hypervisor.framework
thanks @jean